# Fastest and most accurate way to match distorted/transformed image to base image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to take an image taken in through a scanner (or possibly mobile phone camera) of varying quality and distortion, and re-align it with the base image (the one generated through photoshop, before it's printed and scanned) to be as close as possible.

The image has four thick corner points at each of the corners, which I've been using a primitive method to find the four points of, then using a perspective transform on the scanned image.  However, my algorithm is completely brute-force and highly breakable.

I've tried using cvGoodFeaturesToTrack(), but I can't come up with an accurate way of making sure the four points for calibration are accurate under all circumstances.  I've thought of using template matching, but it doesn't seem like it will work reliably under a variety of distortions.  I'm seeing a lot of methods to do specific tasks, like finding contours, key points, lines, etc., but no indications of what do actually *do* with them.

Is there a better way that I'm just not seeing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you dealing with the *possible* distortion caused by the camera lens?

Comment: Well it has to assume the ability to deal with any type of distortion.  I suppose a nearly perfect scan would result in minimal change, but I have to account for low-quality scanners, barrel distortion, improper orientation, etc.  If you're saying what I think you're saying, then something like a thumb print on the lens itself wasn't what I had in mind.

Comment: have you tried a harris corner detector ?. Difficult to give accurate suggestions without seeing images.

Comment: "my algorithm is completely brute-force and highly breakable": what do you mean exactly ? Is it the detection of those corners that fail or is the perspective transform inappropriate ? The classical approach is binarization and blob analysis: find the pixels darker than a threshold and group them when they touch. Keep the group that has a dot shape and an area in the expected range. Compute its center of gravity.

Comment: Did you find a way in the end? I think you need to impose the constraint (somehow) that the sides must end up as straight perpendicular lines. Can this be represented by a homography matrix?

Comment: I used the answered's approach: I put a set of key points on the printed page to be scanned and analyzed, then applied an affine transformation to those key points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classical approach is binarization and blob analysis: find the pixels darker than a threshold and group them when they touch (connected components analysis). Keep the groups that have a dot shape (good circularity) and an area in the expected range. Use the center of gravity. This should be accurate enough for your reference points.

You may want to reduce false detections of the corner dots because of the nearby features in the image. An option for better discriminance is to use rings instead of disks and look for blobs with a hole.

Answer (score 0):

If your distortions can be described as homography, than you can use "ESM" algorithm (Efficient Second Order Minimization, available in CVD library). 
http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/cvd/html/group__gEsm.html

If your distortions include some lense distortions that you can use DIC (Digital image correlation).